# spark streaming different value decoder per kafka topic

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I need to create a Spark streaming that reads from several topic, and uses a different decoder per each topic (each topic contains a different avro-encoded obect):

```
def decode_avro(message):
    schem = avro.schema.parse(open("error_list.avsc").read())
    bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(message)
    decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
    reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schem)
    return reader.read(decoder)

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic, topic2], {
    "metadata.broker.list": brokers}, valueDecoder = decode_avro)
```

I wan't to know if it is possible to specify different decoder callbacks per topic, or if it is possible to know the topic name on the decoder function (on this way I could used the topic name for the avro schema file and decode all messages in the same function)

Thank you

Comment: I am facing the same challenge. I see that this question is more then 1 year old. How did you bypass this obstacle?

Comment: We finally didn't use this aproach (even not using Kafka at all by the moment). I thougth about a try/catch system which jumps to the following decoder if one exception is raised. Is an ugly solution but I didn't find any better one!

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. I found a proper solution for it, so I will add it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

We also have this case where we read from different topics, with different message formats, and then process each topic and store the output into dedicated storage per source topic.
The right way to go here, is to create multiple streams. Stream per topic, in the same application, with the same Spark context. 
Each stream will get the relevant ValueDecoder, and you may still read from multiple topics if they share the same format.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will vote up it, and when I have some time I will test it.